# What's the swift equivalent for 'FBSDKAccessTokenDidChangeNotification'

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I am finally migrating my Facebook SDK wrapper from Objective C to Swift. 
What is the correct replacement for `FBSDKAccessTokenDidChangeNotification`?

When I try to use it I get the following error:

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
       self, 
       selector: #selector(accountChanged(notification:)), 
       name: FBSDKAccessTokenDidChangeNotification,
       object: nil)
 // Use of unresolved identifier 'FBSDKAccessTokenDidChangeNotification'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKAccessToken.h#L36

The name of the notification in Swift is `AccessTokenDidChange` or `AccessTokenDidChangeNotification` depending on your compiling iOS version.

Comment: **iOS 13** - I was struggling to actually access the property (I thought it was a static property in the `AccessToken` class, but I think it's `NSNotification.Name` that's being extended), so I got it working with `NSNotification.Name.AccessTokenDidChange`

Comment: Facebook documantation is big fail.. In 2021, it still describe as FBSDKAccessTokenDidChangeNotification. But NSNotification.Name.AccessTokenDidChange is work.